# Managing PDF report creation with mPDF, CodeIgniter, Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, pdf

I'm creating an dynamic report to a web application, but I'm facing some problems with MVC model, Ajax/jQuery and mPDF.

In my code, user check the available options to build the query. When user press the generation button with jQuery I temporarily store the information of what the user want in a jQuery array.

Then, I send a POST request (using `$.post()`) to my `CI_Controller`, then the model will communicate to generate my query and return the selected information to build the PDF.

All of that is working just fine until now, but I need to open that PDF archive in a new browser page, until now I just saw many symbols of the PDF coding came as return string in my requisition.

How I can open that pdf in a new windows, or get the pdf that came with the requisition or In the view open a new page and open that PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I just change some parameters to save the file in server, them when Ajax call is complete I call the file in a new window.

```
$pdf->Output($file, 'F');

window.open("<?=site_url($file)?>", '_blank');
```